# Вывод товара только один раз

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю вывод товаров:

```
$cart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `user` = '$user[id]' AND `status` = '0' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
 while ($cart_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($cart))
 {
   //тут разметка
  }
```

Выводит все товары которые есть в корзине(таблица `cart`).

Так вот, при добавлении товара в корзину мы записываем в таблицу `cart` id товара - в ячейку **tov** .
И если еще раз добавить тот же товар, хочу сделать чтоб на странице этот товар выводился только один раз.

Как в таком случае должен выглядеть запрос к базе?

Comment: `GROUP BY id` ? o_O

Comment: @LEQADA точно) спасибо, совсем забыл про это. Напишите это как ответ, чтоб я поставить вам + за помощь

Comment: Нажмите на галочку слева от ответа. Эта галочка означает, что вы приняли ответ.

Comment: @LEQADA я в курсе, спасибо. нужно 3мин ожидать чтоб принять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `user` = '$user[id]' AND `status` = '0' GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не требуется вычислений и просто надо выводить товар, можно использовать

```
select distinct(tov), column1, column2 ... from cart
```

Comment: Привет, добро пожаловать на SO на русском. Пожалуйста, пишите на русском языке и используя кириллицу, здесь так принято. Вы можете отредактировать ответ, нажав [edit].